# How to create multiple producer and consumer in kafka using python

Tags: python, opencv, flask, apache-kafka

I'm trying to capture stream from multiple webcam using the rtsp link in flask app and want to show through the browser. To achieve this I created two individual producers, topic and two consumer. After starting the kafka server and running both consumer.py and producer.py, the both streaming is running only for two seconds.

**I want to capture stream from multiple webcam**

***producer.py***

```
import time
import sys
import cv2
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
producer2 = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
topic = 'my-topic'
topic2 = 'my-topic2'


def emit_video():
    print('start emitting')
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://webcam1')
    camera2 = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://webcam2')

    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read()
        success2, frame2 = camera2.read()
        if not success2:
            print("camera issue")
        # png might be too large to emit
        else:
            data = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', frame)[1].tobytes()
            data2 = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', frame2)[1].tobytes()

            future = producer.send(topic, data)
            future2 = producer2.send(topic2, data2)
            try:
                future.get(timeout=60)
                future2.get(timeout=60)
            except KafkaError as e:
                print(e)
                break

            print('.', end='', flush=True)
            # to reduce CPU usage
            # time.sleep(0.2)
        # print()
    # video.release()

    print('done')


emit_video()
```

***and this is my consumer.py***

```
from flask import Flask, Response,render_template
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic', bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
consumer2 = KafkaConsumer('my-topic2', bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

app = Flask(__name__)


def kafkastream():
    for message in consumer:
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + message.value + b'\r\n\r\n')


def kafkastream2():
    print(threading.current_thread().getName())
    for message in consumer2:
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + message.value + b'\r\n\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(kafkastream(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/video_feed2')
def video_feed2():
    return Response(kafkastream2(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What happens when it stops working after two minutes? If it's timing out on the `future.get()` calls, I'd want to know why you're making that call in order to suggest a better alternative.

Comment: first camera streaming run only for two seconds and after that two seconds, second camera just start. After that, producer. py showing "File "src/producer. py", line 29, in emit_video
    data = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', frame)[1].tobytes()
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_base.cpp:145: error: (-10:Unknown error code -10) Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported) in function 'throwOnEror'
"

Comment: Can I use consumer and consumer2 using same port 9092?

Comment: @ArifIbrahim `9092` is the port for the bootstrap server. It absolutely fine to have more than 1 consumer connecting to the same bootstrap server.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Thank you very much. Now I confirmed that my code is fine. The issue was created for using RTSP link. Without rtsp the code runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', frame)[1].tobytes()
```

---

my sample code

```
ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)

producer.send(topic, buffer.tobytes())


delete '[1]'
```